# NonlinearFit with series coefficients

Tags: fitting, series-expansion, nonlinear, parameters

I have a set of data:

```
data = {{-2., 0.979167}, {0., 1.}, {2., 0.959184}, {4., 0.917526}, {6., 
  0.852632}, {8., 0.833333}, {10., 0.770833}, {12., 0.717172}, {14., 
  0.621053}, {16., 0.536842}, {18., 0.452632}, {20., 0.354167}, {22., 
  0.290323}, {24., 0.252747}, {26., 0.195652}, {28., 0.16129}, {30., 
  0.204301}, {32., 0.16129}, {34., 0.2}, {36., 0.217391}, {38., 
  0.217391}, {40., 0.218391}, {42., 0.164835}, {44., 0.140187}, {46., 
  0.146667}, {48., 0.127753}, {50., 0.145455}, {52., 0.208696}, {54., 
  0.330233}, {56., 0.378995}, {58., 0.400881}, {60., 0.502439}, {62., 
  0.663462}, {64., 0.641509}, {66., 3/4}, {68., 0.82266}, {70., 
  0.888325}, {72., 0.900498}, {74., 0.837975}, {76., 0.845411}, {78., 
  0.833333}, {80., 0.817259}, {82., 0.734694}, {84., 0.659794}, {86., 
  0.557789}, {88., 0.507853}, {90., 0.412371}, {92., 0.262136}, {94., 
  0.28}, {96., 0.179245}, {98., 0.187817}, {100., 0.135922}, {102., 
  0.114286}, {104., 0.157895}, {106., 0.144385}, {108., 0.117647}}
```

And I wanted to fit series to find coefficients but I don't know how:

[image]

I know that to the series should be fitted two COMPLEX NUMBERS coefficients.
"n" must be equal 3, there shouldn't be "b" coefficient. The value $9.77333 \times 10^{20}$ might be different.

The Mathematica command:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 1/n*Abs[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = \(-\((n - 1)\)\)/
        2\), \(\((n - 1)\)/2\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(m\)]*Exp[
\*FractionBox[\(I*m*1.55898*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(8\)]*x\), \(2*\[Pi]*3*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(8\)]\)]]*b*Exp[\(-
\*FractionBox[\(5.02545*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]*Abs[x]\), \(2*\[Pi]*3*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(8\)]\)]\)]*Exp[\(-I\) 
\*FractionBox[\(2*\[Pi]*9.77333*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(20\)]*x\), \(3*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(8\)]\)]]\)\)], {Subscript[a, m]}, x, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

Comment: Please post actual code rather than an image. You'll get better help that way. Also, is `n` a known constant?  Is it $a_n$ or $a_m$?

Comment: I added image to show the command which I used. It's $a_{m}$ coefficients which are complex numbers.

Comment: I understand and that is fine.  But you're expecting help but want everyone to attempt to type in the code from the image when you could just supply it?

Comment: I don't know how to paste Mathematica code here to be readable.

Comment: Thanks!  It's true that it isn't very readable here but one can easily paste in the commands and obtain readable code.

Comment: You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. (You're more likely to get help if people can read the code easily.)

Comment: To piggy-back on @MichaelE2 's comment: Is the term 9.77333 times 10^20 correct?  Specifically the 10^20?

Comment: Term 9.77333 times 10^20 might be not correct.

Comment: Once you replace the formula in my answer, the code should still work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
n = 5;
Array[a, n, {-1, 1} (n - 1)/2]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (1/n)*Abs[Sum[a[m]*
  E^((0. + 0.08270645772713434*I)*(-2.4749233673632412*^14 + m)*
  x - 0.0026660840292038845*Abs[x]), {m, -(n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2}]],
  Table[a[i], {i, -(n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2}], x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a[-2] -> 2.03091, a[-1] -> 1.86209, a[0] -> 1.05792, a[1] -> 0.128069, a[2] -> 0.0179921} *)

Show[Plot[nlm[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

I've removed the parameter $b$ because the product $b a_m$ is estimable but the individual parameters $b$ and $a_m$ are not.

If you want to determine which value of $n$ is best, then you should consider using AICc.  That results in $n=13$ is the best fit (of the models considered).

```
n =.;
nMax = 19;
Array[a, nMax, {-1, 1} (nMax - 1)/2]
aic = Table[{n, NonlinearModelFit[data, (1/n)*Abs[Sum[a[m]*
  E^((0. + 0.08270645772713434*I)*(-2.4749233673632412*^14 + m)*x -
  0.0026660840292038845*Abs[x]), {m, -(n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2}]], 
  Table[a[i], {i, -(n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2}], x]["AICc"]}, {n, 1, nMax, 2}];
ListPlot[aic, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Black] &) /@ {"n", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(AIC\), \(c\)]\)"}]
```

[image: n vs AICc]

Comment: I wonder about that `(-2.47492*10^14 + m)`....If I change it to `m`, I get a better looking fit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5kei.png (less error from range reduction in compute `E^(I * (<bignum> + m)x)` perhaps).

Comment: $n$ must be equal to 3.

Comment: I don't know the subject matter so I can't justify selecting other values of $n$.  However, even if there is some subject matter consideration that requires $n=3$, if other values of $n$ give lower $AIC_c$ values, then that suggests more examination of the data collection method.